# I can't figure out why the list isn't loading

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I can't figure out why the **TodoList** doesn't load immediately when I enter the app. Instead of a list, I get a TodoEmptyState status, even if I already have saved items in the DB, it's still an empty list at first. But after that, when I add a new element and update it, then it will load.
But I want the list to be immediately loaded (if there are saved items) when entering the application without clicking on the buttons. **Please tell me how to do it?**

**home_screen**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<TodoBloc, TodoState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter Todos'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TodoList(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

**todo_list**

```
class TodoList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TodoBloc todoBloc = context.read<TodoBloc>();
    return BlocBuilder<TodoBloc, TodoState>(builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is TodoEmptyState) {
        return const Center(
          child: Text(
            'No Todo',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        );
      }

      if (state is TodoLoadingState) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      if (state is TodoLoadedState) {
        return ListView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: state.loadedUser.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                // return _buildListTile(state.loadedUser[index]);
                ListTile(
                  title: Column(children: [
                    Text('${state.loadedUser[index].description}'),
                    Text('${state.loadedUser[index].id}'),
                  ]),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      todoBloc.add(DeleteTodos(id: state.loadedUser[index].id));
                      todoBloc.add(LoadTodos());
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                  ),
                ));
      }
      return const SizedBox.shrink();
    });
  }
}
```

**todo_bloc**

```
class TodoBloc extends Bloc<TodoEvent, TodoState> {
  final TodoRepository todoRepository;

  TodoBloc(this.todoRepository) : super(TodoEmptyState()) {
    on<LoadTodos>((event, emit) async {
      emit(TodoLoadingState());
      try {
        final List<Todo> _loadedTodoList = await todoRepository.getAllTodos();
        emit(TodoLoadedState(loadedUser: _loadedTodoList));
      } catch (_) {
        emit(TodoErrorState());
      }
    });
```

Here is the screen when entering the application, but I already have data in the DB, but they were not immediately displayed. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the only place you add any event to your bloc is inside `onPressed` of the `IconButton` which is why your bloc state remains in its initial state `TodoEmptyState` and doesn't change until the `IconButton` is pressed. You can convert your `TodoList` to a `StatefulWidget` and add the `LoadTodos` event to the bloc in `initState`:

```
class TodoList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TodoList> createState() => _TodoListState();
}

class _TodoListState extends State<TodoList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    todoBloc.add(LoadTodos());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    todoBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TodoBloc todoBloc = context.read<TodoBloc>();
    return BlocBuilder<TodoBloc, TodoState>(builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is TodoEmptyState) {
        return const Center(
          child: Text(
            'No Todo',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        );
      }

      if (state is TodoLoadingState) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      if (state is TodoLoadedState) {
        return ListView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: state.loadedUser.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
            // return _buildListTile(state.loadedUser[index]);
            ListTile(
              title: Column(children: [
                Text('${state.loadedUser[index].description}'),
                Text('${state.loadedUser[index].id}'),
              ]),
              trailing: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  todoBloc.add(DeleteTodos(id: state.loadedUser[index].id));
                  todoBloc.add(LoadTodos());
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              ),
            ));
      }
      return const SizedBox.shrink();
    });
  }
}
```